# Load content into div using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html-parsing

I'm Loading in content from view_login.php into index.php´s `div id="display"` using ajax javascript

```
var hr=new XMLHttpRequest();
hr.open("GET", 'view_login.php', true);
hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send();
```

Rather than `echo $output` i would just target the div itself.

PHP/HTML

```
$output = '
<div id="visible">
<form>
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</div>';

echo $output;
```

is it possible to just target the div `visible` and it contents instead of every ouput on the page? without using jquery and just plain/raw javascript.

Comment: did you even bother to read entire page?

Comment: i think regex could work, but i dont know how to start out with it.

Comment: Surely, if you want to just target the div with id `visible`, you would should do `document.getElementById('visible')` or is that not an option? And I don't know what regex is supposed to do in this case, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this in plain JavaScript. One way would be to append the HTML to a [Document Fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), which is a separate document, then use `querySelector` on it to pull out just the div you want.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G9Sa6/)**

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var div = document.createElement('div'); // create a div to contain the HTML
div.innerHTML = return_data; // insert HTML to the div
frag.appendChild(div); // append the div to the document fragment

var visibleDiv = frag.querySelector("#visible"); // find the #visible div

// append the div to the main document
document.getElementById('display').appendChild(visibleDiv);
```

Other options are:

- [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) (supported by IE9+).
- Append it as a div to the main document, but you'll need to make sure it's hidden from view, then get the div and remove it.